# Extract only the First set of numbers in a String

Tags: regex, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a string like below:

```
input = Test_8234_and_2345_end
REG_EXTRACT(input,'(\d+)',1)
```

I'm trying to create a regex that targets only the first set of numbers (i.e 8234) in the above string but it it returns none. what is wrong with my above code.

Comment: don't know informatica but shouldn't be `\1` instead of `1`?

Comment: @snoram No that  didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Informatica, but the following Regex pattern should work if you disable the greedy global modifier for the pattern:

```
(?<=_)[0-9]*
```

I used the regex101.com online regex calculator to test the pattern and it worked with Python.

Comment: Thanks that was working. Based on your code, I have tried the below code as well and it was working too. Just curious how to select only the numbers that are 4 digits with the below code.Tried adding {4} to the below code but no luck.  [0-9]+

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if making the pattern match four digits was too specific. The pattern `(?<=_)[0-9]{4}` should work. It might have something to do with Informatica. If that doesn't work you can try `(?<=_)[0-9]*(?<=\B)` which will capture all digits between underscores.